# Citation Style in LyX

Tags: lyx, citing

I am using LyX on Max OS X. When I insert a citation and I compile the document I get a reference number between square brackets that matches the number of the reference in the bibliography section.

e.g. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [5].

How do I display the above reference in the following style:

e.g. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet (Smith et ala).

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To use author-year style citations, go to Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, choose *Natbib*, and *Author-year* as *Natbib style*, as in the screen shot below.

Note that if you write your own bibliography, you have to make sure you get the correct format, as described in section **2.2 The Syntax of the thebibliography** of the [`natbib` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/natbib). In LyX, to add the optional argument (what is in the square brackets) to the `\bibitem`, click where it says e.g. `key-1[]`, and add the text in the *Label* field, as in the bottom screenshot.

[image]

[image]