# LyX: Citation shows up as [#] rather than (Author, Year)

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I've been having the same problem as this [person](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129054/citation-style-in-lyx). My citations show up as [#], and not in the desired format (Author, Year).

I have checked natbib as advised:
[image]

, and also in the citation menu itself:
[image]

However, the PDF prints still only give me [#]. Any ideas?

Edit: My BibTex is an export file from Mendeley, and looks quite normal.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: What document class are you using? Would the problem persist if you switch to a different document class, say `article`?

Comment: I'm using Article (Komascript)

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using? Try `plainnat`.

Answer (score 2):

At least for the class "elsarticle" (Elsevier), the document class is loaded with a numbered citation style by default. For elsarticle, one adds the year by adding the "authoryear" option to the class by doing this in LyX: Document -> Settings -> Document Class -> Class options -> Custom: "authoryear"

Source: [elsarticle documentation](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/latex-instructions)

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the Elsevier template elsarticle-template-1-num.tex in a raw editor without these options you have to add the option

```
\biboptions{authoryear}
```